# Is there is an autocompletion feature for brackets in Mathematica 10?

Tags: autocomplete, wolfram-mathematica, brackets, code-assist

I am new to Mathematica, have used RStudio before for R and like the feature for brackets' autocompletion. There are plenty of different brackets are used in Mathematica code and it is handy to have same feature there. May be I just missed where the setting for it is?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Insert -> Typesetting to find the keyboard shortcuts for inserting matching `[]`, `()` or `{}`.  On OS X it's Option-Command-`]`.

There's information on matching brackets [in the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/BalanceBracketsAndBraces.html).

---

The good news is that this functionality is much less needed in Mathematica than in R.  In Mathematica, instead of writing

```
f[g[h[x]]]
```

I like to write the completely equivalent but much more readable

```
f@g@h[x]
```

Instead of writing

```
lapply(arr, f)
```

we would write

```
f /@ arr
```

in Mathematica.  This is equivalent to `Map[f, arr]` but has no brackets.

It's worth putting in some time to learn how to use [these weird looking operators](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/12) effectively. While it's certainly possible to use them to make your code cryptic and unintelligible, when used correctly, they can improve readability significantly. It just requires experience and a little discipline.  I recommend you look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ to get used to the idiomatic use of these operators.

While learning Mathematica keep in mind that there is a subjective (or "cultural") element to "readability".  You'll need to get used to the community standards and common idioms before all of this starts making sense.  That's why I suggest reading Mathematica.SE.

---

**Update:**  I forgot to mention the somewhat annoying `[[ ... ]]` notation for `Part`.  Go to the bottom [my Mathematica page](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/pages/mathematica.html) to see how to set up keyboard shortcuts for inserting the equivalent but more readable `〚`.  <kbd>esc</kbd> `[` <kbd>esc</kbd> also works but I find it too tedious.